# External links in my footer are not working?

Tags: html, css

I am building a website and everything has been fine until I got to my footer. I am trying to have a facebook and twitter icon that redirect to the according pages, but for some reason the links in my footer will not work at all. They won't redirect to the specific page or the general facebook and twitter homepages, and even if I change it from an image to a text hyperlink it doesn't work. It seems any links I have in my footer just don't respond. I have checked the code repeatedly and can't find an issue, and I know all images are saved in the right place. The icons show up, the mouse changes to a pointer when hovering, but nothing happens when you click. I only reference a.nav in my CSS, I have not edited the normal a tag with CSS.

```css
footer {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <p>&copy; 2017 The Michigan Spirits Association | All Rights Reserved</p>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
        <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="MSA Facebook" style="width:15px">
    </a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com">
        <img src="images/twitter.png" alt="MSA Twitter" style="width:15px">
    </a>
</footer>
```

Comment: You may have to show some more code as this alone doesn't allow us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings in the browser console? Also, have you tried plain text links?

Comment: I have tried changing the images to text links, yes, and the same thing happens. Links will not redirect or do anything when clicking. I am using Dreamweaver, and when I hover over the link in the a tag the message "image not found" appears, although that is a link not an image. And the images I am using (the icons) are showing up just fine. I can show more code if needed, just let me know.

Comment: Show us the full html&css on jsfiddle.net. Make sure that the issue will be produced there.

Comment: Sorry, I have never used jsfiddle, can you tell me how so share my results? I did notice one thing- the image I have on the top of the page did not load and showed as an empty box with the blue question mark inside to signal a missing image. The two icons in the footer, however, just showed as two empty white outlined boxes. There was no question mark inside them. It looked somewhat like is you are sent an emoji your device doesn't support and you just get a blank rectangle.

Comment: Maybe try changing the URL to the correct `https` protocol instead of `http`.

Comment: Changed URL protocols to https, still not working.

Comment: @AdamAwdish your code is properly work in my PC, please share your full html code to find the error.

Comment: @Adam Also, try to add `target="_blank"` to `<a>` tag.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle version of your problem?

Comment: @Oleksandr FINALLY! I added target="blank" to the a tags and now both icons link to the correct pages! Could you explain to me why this makes them work for future reference, and what was causing them to be broken until I edited the target? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your HTML codes and CSS it working properly, I have clicked on them and its responding the facebook.com and twitter.com correctly based on your mentioned link in your HTML coding
Maybe you should clear your browser cache and all history, I am sure it will work

Answer (score 0):

I have just replaced the directory links to the image elements on the web links and it worked for me too.

```css
footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/540/facebook.png" alt="MSA Facebook" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"></a>
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com"><img src="http://www.freepngimg.com/thumb/twitter/2-2-twitter-png-file-thumb.png" alt="MSA Twitter" style="width: 15px; heigth: 15px;"></a>
    </footer>
```